# How to get Facebook Feeds (post) using facebook sdk 4.0 in android?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have show facebook feeds(post) list in may application. I am using facebook 4.0 I am able to get profile but unable to fetch all my feeds(post). If anybody have any reference then please tell me. Thanks.

Right-now I am using following code for get Feeds but getting blank response like {"data":[]}

```
FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            new GraphRequest(
                     AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                     loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()+"/feed/",
                     null,
                     HttpMethod.GET,
                     new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                         public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                             Log.i("fb", "Feeds :" +response.getJSONObject());
                             Toast.makeText(
                                     getApplicationContext(),
                                     response.getJSONObject()
                                             + "",
                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     }
             ).executeAsync();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a graph api call from within your app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed

Answer (score 1):

Here,

You are not passing parameters like these:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "message,created_time,id,full_picture,status_type,source,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true)");
        params.putString("limit", "10");


/* make the API call */
        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/userId/posts", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        /* handle the result */
                        System.out.println("Festival Page response::" + String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

Hope to solving these issue i am solving into **facebook SDK 4.6.0**

Comment: In this way can we achieve the related images of post?
`Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "message,created_time,id,full_picture,status_type,source,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true)");
        params.putString("limit", "10");`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `user_posts` permission to your login request:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
Arrays.asList("public_profile ", "user_status","user_posts"));
```